# Can glmmTMB estimate this type of model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, glmmtmb

I am trying to estimate a mixed effects model with a random effect that is subject to both **cross-correlation** across groups and **auto-correlation** over time within groups. Can this be done with glmmTMB?

An example would be the assumption that the property market is driven by three different latent price processes for the groups *commercial,* *residential* and *industrial* property. Each of the segment price process would feature correlation with its own lagged values (autocorrelation) and correlation with the other two price processes for a given time period.

The formulation I tried for glmmTMB is:

*glmmTMB(y ~ fixed+ar1(timestep+0|group), data=outcome_table)*

I have included some R code that generates data and applies the estimation procedure at the end of my post.

In the simulation study, the parameters are estimate quite well. It is still not clear to me whether the formulation exactly corresponds to what I want to measure. Also, an alternative formulation of the model that disregards the AR1 nature of the process gives me estimation results of almost the same quality when it comes to estimating the cross correlation.

*glmmTMB(y ~ fixed+(-1+group|timestep), data=outcome_table)*

It is also not clear to me how I should identify the cross correlation between the time periods, because VarCorr() only gives me a correlation tabel that covers the correlation across time (i.e. a timestep x timestep matrix).

I can of course infer the cross correlaton directly based on the BLUPs for the random effects, but I know that inference based on the BLUPs directly can be misleading.

So what is the correct formulation, or is the model I am looking for not possible with glmmTMB at all?

```
require(glmmTMB);require(tsDyn);require(data.table)

  #Initialize parameters
  n <- 200  #time periods
  groupcount <- 3 #number of groups
  members_in_group <- 30   #members per group
  epsilon_std <- 2  #Random Noise Standard Deviation

  #Cross Sectional Variance Covariance Matrix
  covariance <- 0.8 #Cross Sectional covariance
  variance_per_group <- runif(1,0,2) #Different variance of random effect per group
  #variance_per_group <- 1 #Different variance of random effect per group
  varcovmatrix <- diag(groupcount)+covariance-covariance*diag(groupcount)+diag(groupcount)*variance_per_group

  #AR1 Process Matrix (no off-diagonal elements, i.e. no correlation with lags of other random effects)
  arparameter <- 0.9 #Ar Parameter, identical per group
  ar_corrmatrix <- diag(groupcount)*arparameter

  #Draw realization of random effects over time and groups
  re_table <- data.table(group=as.factor(rep(1:groupcount,each=n))
                         ,timestep=as.factor(1:n),
                         x=as.vector(VAR.sim(B=ar_corrmatrix,n=n,include="none",varcov=varcovmatrix)))

  #Draw members in group (maximum of) and select randomly  80% of portfolio (in order to get unbalanced portfolios)
  for (i in 1:members_in_group){
    if (i==1) outcome_table <- re_table[sample(1:.N,0.8*.N)]
    if (i>1) outcome_table <- rbind(outcome_table,re_table[sample(1:.N,0.8*.N)])
  }

  #Add fixed factors and random noise
  outcome_table[,fixed:=runif(.N,1,4)]
  outcome_table[,y:=3+fixed+x+rnorm(.N)*epsilon_std]

  #Old model without ar 1 random effects specification
  model_old <- glmmTMB(y ~ fixed+(-1+group|timestep), data=outcome_table,control=glmmTMBControl(optCtrl = list(iter.max=1e4,eval.max=1e4)))

    #Model with AR1 specification
  model_with_ar <- glmmTMB(y ~ fixed+ar1(timestep+0|group), data=outcome_table)

  #Extract random effects for both models
  re_model_with_ar <- t(ranef(model_with_ar)$cond$group)
  re_model_old <- ranef(model_old)$cond$timestep

  #Derive "empiric" correlation matrix based on simulation
  simulated_re_values <- cor(dcast(re_table,timestep~group,value.var="x")[,!"timestep"])

  #Differnce between correlation matrix based on extracted random effects and "empiric" correlation matrix
  delta_with_ar <- cor(re_model_with_ar)-simulated_re_values
  delta_old <- cor(re_model_old)-simulated_re_values

  sum(delta_with_ar^2);sum(delta_old^2)
```